# Why isn't my raycast intersecting anything?

Tags: three.js

I have this code, designed to find the mesh the user is clicking on:

```js
// scene and camera are defined outside of this code
var mousePoint = new THREE.Vector2();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var intersections;

function onClick(event) {
  mousePoint.x = event.clientX;
  mousePoint.y = event.clientY;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePoint, camera);
  intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(
    scene.children);
}
```

Yet every time I click, `intersections` comes back as an empty array, with nothing getting intersected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the three.js documentation for Raycaster](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Raycaster) (emphasis mine):

> `.setFromCamera ( coords, camera )`
>
> `coords` — 2D coordinates of the mouse, **in normalized device coordinates (NDC)---X and Y components should be between -1 and 1.**
>   `camera` — camera from which the ray should originate
>
> Updates the ray with a new origin and direction.

Therefore, when setting the coordinates of `mousePoint`, instead of setting `x` and `y` directly to `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`, they should be converted to this coordinate space:

```js
// calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
// (-1 to +1) for both components
mousePoint.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mousePoint.y = (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * -2 + 1;
```